# I am getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

Its the same program that I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734214/what-is-wrong-with-my-androidmanifest-xml).
I fixed that problem, but now when I launch it, it crashes, and get:

```
W/dalvikvm(  316): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/wingdom/convention/Map; (12)
W/dalvikvm(  316): Link of class 'Lcom/wingdom/convention/Map;' failed
E/dalvikvm(  316): Could not find class 'com.wingdom.convention.Map', referenced from method com.wingdom.convention.TabWidget.onCreate
W/dalvikvm(  316): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 13 (Lcom/wingdom/convention/Map;) in Lcom/wingdom/convention/TabWidget;
D/dalvikvm(  316): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x003a
D/dalvikvm(  316): VFY: dead code 0x003c-005e in Lcom/wingdom/convention/TabWidget;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
D/AndroidRuntime(  316): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  316): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  316): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.wingdom.convention.Map
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at com.wingdom.convention.TabWidget.onCreate(TabWidget.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  316):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(   59):   Force finishing activity com.wingdom.convention/.TabWidget
```

The app has 3 activity classes, TabWidget, Schedule, and Map (Map is actually a MapActivity, but its blank right now, want the app to run first). TabWidget is almost exactly the HelloTabWidget learning example given at the android developer site. Schedule is just a list of text. If you need to see any code to help fix it, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a word: "classpath".  The class loader can't find com.wingdom.convention.Map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Make sure to add this as a child of your application in the manifest. This will stop the crash.

You'll need to add the Internet permission as a child of your manifest as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To use MapActivity, you need to setup a virtual device that includes the Google APIs.  Setting up just a vanilla Android virtual device isn't good enough.

Look [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#avdsetup) for more information:

Comment: I am using a virtual device that is Google API, Platform 2.2, Level 8. I read the intro on using a MapActivity. It crashes on the Virtual Device, and my Droid Incredible, with roughly the same error log.

Comment: Weird.  I was basing my answer on the first line of errors:  Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/wingdom/convention/Map; (12)

Comment: In which case I refer you back to duffymo: 90% of all Java problems are CLASSPATH-related.

Comment: what do you make of:
E/AndroidRuntime(  316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  316): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.wingdom.convention.Map

Comment: It can find the class just fine...the issue is that the superclass map library needs to be defined in the manifest