# using jar in different OS

Tags: java, android, jar

I have created a jar file in Eclipse of my Java project in JRE 1.7 compliance level in Windows 7 OS. The generated jar is running well on my system in a sample test application.

Now I want to use this jar in my android application on Mac OS with JRE 1.6.0. Will any conflict arise due to this because there are errors like `ClassNotFound Exception` in android application using ADT 20 or `davlik conversion failed error 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have your android project compiling on the other platform you need to make sure that the Android API level you target in your application is installed on it. I wouldn't think that any of the features of Java 1.7 are causing the trouble, because Android sdk will either way restrict you from using them.

The change of the operating systems should not cause any problems - this is why they say that Java is platform independent.

Comment: Yes, Boris...I am well confirm about Platform independency of Java. Android API level that is targeted is installed in the system. However when I am trying to use this Jar file in android application there are errors of Class Definition Not Found Exception.. or  Could not find class 'org.AstroVed.Panchanga.Moment', referenced from method com.astroved.horawatch.HoraWatchActivity.onCreate error.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: @KumarShorav can you post the whole text of some of this errors? What does your accept on the answer mean: did you find the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356232/adding-external-jar-in-adt-20-in-android-application-projects

Please have a look on this question. I am struggling with this.